# Rails has_many, find only those with children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My "products" table has_many :registered_products.

I want to use something like

```
products.find(:has_registered_products)
```

where that will return only the products that also have an entry in the registered_products table.  How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you have a foreign_key for the product in the registered_products table you can do:

```
has_many :registered_products
named_scope :with_registered_products, :joins => :registered_products

# if you're using rails 3
scope :with_registered_products, joins(:registered_products)
```

and that will only return products that have at least one associated registered product.

Comment: don't forget to select it as distinct or you'll end up with duplicates here is mine: `scope :at_least_one_image, select('DISTINCT recipes.*').joins(:images)`

Answer (score 5):

This will handle the duplication.

```
Product.joins(:registered_products).uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jakob points out, if there are multiple child records, you need to ensure that you are not returning multiple parent objects.

Using the "select distinct" will work, but the select statement could interfere when this scope is combined with other scopes.

Another option is to ensure that you join to a child table that only has unique records. You can do this by composing your join as follows

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many registered_products

 scope :with_registered_products, joins('join (select distinct product_id from registered_products) rp123456 on rp123456.product_id = products.id')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product
  has_many :registered_products
end
```

List of Products (with at-least one registered product) - Eager loaded registered products

```
Product.all(:include => :registered_products, 
  :conditions => "registered_products.id IS NULL")
```

List of Products (with at-least one registered product) - Without eager loading

```
Product.all(:joins => :registered_products)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use counter_cache (http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).  It should be faster than actually doing the join just to find out if there are any children.