# How to return only items with existing (not nil) relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have model User and model Car.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cars, dependent: :nullify
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What is the simplest way to return only users with existing cars? Something like `users.with_cars`

Comment: User.joins(:cars)

Comment: [Rails has_many, find only those with children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426463/rails-has-many-find-only-those-with-children)

Comment: `User.joins(:cars).distinct` should solve your problem. It use 'INNER JOIN', an another option is 'includes' which use 'LEFT OUTER JOIN': `User.includes(:cars).where.not(cars: {id: nil})`